# Error in file upload using perl "read() on unopened filehandle"

Tags: perl, cgi

I am facing read the file error while i am uploading a file using perl like this

```
           fileparse_set_fstype('MSWin32');
            my ($OriginalName,$OriginalPath) = fileparse( $CgiRef->{'filename'} );
            my $LocalName = $_ . $OriginalName;

            open(FILE, ">$config->{'BASE_PATH'}/files/$LocalName")
               or die "Could not open file:$!";
            my $Req = new CGI;
            while (read($Req->param('filename'), my $Buffer, 1024))
            {
               print FILE $Buffer;
            }
        close(FILE)
```

And There is no problem in accesing `$CgiRef->{'$filename'}` or any refernce variables.
please let me know where is the actual problem while uploading.
now it shows the error
read() on unopened filehandle

Comment: What is `$CgiRef`? How is it different to `$Req`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read from the wrong place. In CGI-land, use `$cgi->upload('varname')` to get a filehandle on the object you're trying to receive.

This modified version of your snippet should work:

```
 fileparse_set_fstype('MSWin32');

 my ($OriginalName,$OriginalPath) = fileparse( $CgiRef->{'filename'} );
 my $LocalName = $_ . $OriginalName;

 open(FILE, ">", "$config->{'BASE_PATH'}/files/$LocalName")
     or die "Could not open file:$!";

 my $Req = CGI->new();

 # Get the filehandle for the upload content
 my $Req_file = $Req->upload('filename');

 # Save to FILE
 while (<$Req_file>) {
     print FILE;
 }
 close(FILE);
```

Please note, always use the 3 param version of `open`. It's cleaner, safer, and clearer. See [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) for an explanation.

A full example of the whole process from HTML form to CGI processing can be found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-files-cgi-perl/).